# Select image id

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to grab the  id of the image that is clicked and then submit it with the form (by setting the val of the hidden imagenr input). However I don't know how to pull the id.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".test-img").click(function () {

                var imagevar = // How to grab the clicked img id?
                $("#imagenr").val(imagevar); // set the img id to the hidden input
                $("form#test-form").submit(); // submit the form

            })
        })




<form action="#" method="post" id="test-form">
<input type="hidden" name="imagenr" id="imagenr" value="">

<img class="test-img" id="1" src="images/image1.jpg" alt=""/>
<img class="test-img" id="2" src="images/image2.jpg" alt=""/>

</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `this.id`, no need to wrap it in jQuery.

```
var imagevar = this.id;
```

**[Example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/8dmCz/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".test-img").click(function () {
   var imagevar = $(this).attr('id');
   $("#imagenr").val(imagevar); // set the img id to the hidden input
   $("form#test-form").submit(); // submit the form
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".test-img").click(function () {

            var imagevar = $(this).attr('id');
            $("#imagenr").val(imagevar); // set the img id to the hidden input
            $("form#test-form").submit(); // submit the form

        })
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can grab the value of any attribute directly, using something like:

```
$(this).attr('id');
```

Good luck.